# How to Restrict user to have more than one territory?

Tags: community, user, error-messages, territory-management, territory

I want to show an error message when admin tries to associate the user of a particular profile with more than one territory. The user of this profile should be assigned to one territory only. If the user should have one territory if he belongs to a particular profile How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your query, I will give you a brief on what I know about **territory management**. Whenever you add a user to a territory a record gets created in the object `UserTerritory2Association`.

The `UserTerritory2Association` object will have a mapping of the `Territory2Id` and `UserId`

**So you will have to restrict the record creation when a second entry is being created for a particular user.**

You can achieve it by using a `trigger` like below, which checks whether the user being inserted is already present in the `UserTerritory2Association` object.

Below trigger code is for reference. You can modify it, to write in a better way using a handler class.

```
trigger MyUserTerritoryAssociationTrigger on UserTerritory2Association(before insert) {
    //Trigger logic
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,UserTerritory2Association> mapUserTerritoryMap = new Map<Id,UserTerritory2Association>();
    for(UserTerritory2Association u: Trigger.new) {
        userIds.add(u.UserId);
    }

    for(UserTerritory2Association uTObj: [SELECT Id, UserId FROM UserTerritory2Association WHERE UserId IN :userIDs]){
        mapUserTerritoryMap.put(uTObj.UserId, uTObj);
    }

    for(UserTerritory2Association u: Trigger.new) {
        if(mapUserTerritoryMap.containsKey(u.UserId)) {
            u.addError('User is already a member of another Territory');
        }
    }

}
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Hi Hemant, 
But there is no object Like "UserTerritory2Association" .  
UserTerritory and Territory object is there.  So I am not sure on which object I have to write trigger.  Can you please help on this

Comment: `UserTerritory2Association`object is present if enterprise territory management is enabled. I suppose in your case the territory and user mapping would be stored in `UserTerritoy` object. But I suppose salesforce doesn't allow a trigger on `UserTerritory` object.